# Can I ensure the cell is written with date or time format with Pandas Xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am writing file creation times into an Excel table using Pandas Xlsxwriter however I could not find where I could specify cell format.
As a result my timestamps come out as text in Excel

Here is the relevant part of my code

```
for d, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for f in files:
        full_name = path.join(d, f)
        if path.isfile(full_name):
             time_info = [(fn(full_name)) for fn in (path.getatime, path.getmtime, path.getctime)]
             dict1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(time_info[0]).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'), datetime.fromtimestamp(time_info[0]).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')]
             dict2.append(dict1)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict2, columns=('the last access time', 'time changes')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('listdir1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter',   datetime_format='dd.mm.yyyy', date_format='dd.mm.yyyy')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Here is how it looks in Excel

[image: example]

Comment: The syntax of the date/time formatting look okay and are in line with the XlsxWriter [documentation on Formatting of the Dataframe output](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output). However, looking at your screenshot the dates are aligned to the left of the cell which generally means that they are strings and not numbers and in Excel dates are numbers with formatting. So I'd guess that the dates in your dataframe are actually strings or some part of the process is converting them to strings.

Comment: If you want excel cells to hold date, time or numeric value you should not convert your `datetime`s to strings with `strftime`. Instead make sure your `dict1` holds `datetime` value, not strings.